# Geany regex to extract data inside and outside parenthesis separately

Tags: regex, geany

I have an incomplete XML file I am trying to convert to CSV to map to a spreadsheet. To create the header I need to extract the label before each `=` and seperate with a `,`.

Inversely, I need to capture everything between the `""` on all the lines to match up to the header.

Where I'm having trouble is there are some spaces in some of the data fields which is messing me up in creating anchors, and some fields have no data at all with just `""`. Here is a sample with both cases in which I was trying to create my header.

```
lvendor="EBL" lxref="1304112" linked="0" ltrnqty="" labeltype="ITEM W/DATE,VENDOR" taxcode="1" foodstamp="false" nonstock="false" detail="true" ars2="false"
```

The Geany regex I tried with is:

```
[=]["](\S+)?["][\s]
```

This works until I run into a space in the data field, but replacing `(\S+)?` with `(.+)?` gives me other problems. I'm just not sure how to anchor my regex properly, or if I need to use a capture group to get it done.

I'm not even positive if Geany is the right tool here. I'm on an [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) box, so I'm open to any tools that are available to me.

Comment: did you try an online tool: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=xml+to+csv&oq=xml+to+csv&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2764j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

[`(\w+)(?==)|"([^"]*)"`](https://regex101.com/r/gq4JmF/2)

This will save the variable names on first capturing group and their corresponding values on the second capturing group.

Comment: This addressed both labels and the data. I had thought of capturing, but not the either-or. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are open to new tools, you can convert XML to CSV easily in the terminal with `sed`:

```
cat file.xml | sed -r 's/\s?\S+=/,/g' | sed -r 's/^,//'
```